# How to add 2-nd input value with nusoap?

Tags: php, xml, soap, nusoap

I have created server based on nusoap library. I can make it work with 1 input value, and it returns string output, but when i want to add additional input for function and nusoap function, it is not working and returning nothing, It is not passing values to function. Where am I wrong? What should i do to make it working with 2 input values? Also I will be glad if someone tell me how can i make output xml, not string.

```html
function getDataByName($first, $second)
{
  $xml = code here;
  
  return $xml;
}

require_once("path_to_lib/nusoap.php");
$server = new soap_server();
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
$server->configureWSDL("INFO_BY_NAME");
//$server->register("getDataByName",array('name'=>"xsd:string", 'surname'=>"xsd:string"),array('return'=>"xsd:string"));
$server->register('getDataByName',
    array ('first' => 'xsd:string', 'second' => 'xsd:string'),           // input parameters
    array('return'=>'xsd:string'),             // output parameters
    'urn:IINFO_BY_NAME',                            // namespace
    'urn:INFO_BY_NAME#getDataByName',                // SOAPAction
    'rpc',                                     // style
    'encoded',                                 // use
    'Returns a list of info');
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```